# Had there been a non-flying pterosaur?

Tags: entomology, reptile

Since there are non-flying birds and secondary non-flying insects, it is reasonable to assume there were also non-flying pterosaurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, according to this source there are no flightless bats, so it isn't an absolute that all flying clades have flightless members:

https://pterosaurheresies.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/meet-the-first-flightless-pterosaur-sos-2428/

> Everyone knows about the various flightless birds: the penguin, the dodo, the ostrich… the list goes on. There are no flightless bats. And no one has ever discovered a flightless pterosaur… until now.

But the short answer to your question is: **no confirmed flightless pterosaur fossil seems to have been discovered so far**.

The longer answer is: from what I can tell no pterosaur has been found that was clearly flightless, but pterosaur flight isn't well-understood in the first place so there is debate as to how and whether some specimens could have flown. It seems to be the consensus so far that they did fly however (based on the lack of mention of flightlessness on the Wikipedia page, and the last paper I link to in this answer is fairly convincing).

As far as not finding flightless specimen, the above link claims to have found one but the source is not reputable and I found no confirmation of it elsewhere (Wikipedia confirms, and I'm usually all about Wikipedia but here the page has all the hallmarks of having been written by the same person who wrote the blog). The same author argues a large pterosaur is flightless [here](http://beforeitsnews.com/science-and-technology/2013/11/was-hatzegopteryx-flightless-2654454.html), but their arguments are quite poor compared to others made in the field and they seem again to be the only ones making them.

[Here is a post from Tetrapod Zoology in 2008](http://scienceblogs.com/tetrapodzoology/2008/09/22/come-back-lank/) imagining what a flightless pterosaur might be like, and also claiming none have been found:

> Long-time readers will know that I am an unashamed fan of both speculative zoology, and of Dougal Dixon’s hypothetical ‘alternative’ animals. Inspired by a comment made here in August by Jenny Islander, I have been having a re-think about the possible evolution of flightless pterosaurs: the fossil record gives no indication that such animals ever existed, and maybe they didn’t, but that hasn’t stopped people from speculating.

A similar quote from [the 2004 book "Posture, Locomotion, and Paleoecology of Pterosaurs"](https://books.google.fr/books?hl=en&lr=&id=idta6AVV-tIC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&ots=2G-08W8aQx&sig=zyueUAsMKrourgu5gBE3kejXXWo&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=flightless&f=false):

> So far, there is no example of flightless pterosaurs.

[The Wikipedia page for pterosaurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pterosaur#Flight) makes it clear how hard it is to figure out how pterosaurs flew.

[Here is one of the main arguments that the largest pterosaur *Quetzalcoatlus northropi* was flightless](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/02724631003758334)

> The estimated mass for the largest pterosaur known, Quetzalcoatlus northropi, exceeds the previous highest estimates by more than 100%, and it is argued that this extremely large pterosaur is better interpreted as a secondarily flightless form.

[And an argument that the largest pterosaurs would have been flightless based on a comparison to modern oceangoing birds](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0005400):

> Our result therefore casts doubt on the flying ability of large, extinct pterosaurs. The largest extant soarer, the wandering albatross, weighs about 12 kg, which might be a pragmatic limit to maintain a safety margin for sustainable flight and to survive in a variable environment.

[This paper summarizes the debates and argues against those assessments (the whole paper is worth reading actually):](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0013982)

> While the conclusions on giant pterosaur flight by Chatterjee and Templin [19], Sato et al. [17], Henderson [25] and other workers using avian analogues for pterosaurs are not without merit, we find that they leave themselves open to criticism by not considering alternative data sources when making inferences about the palaeobiology of extinct animals. Giant pterosaur anatomy, functional morphology and, in the case of Pteranodon at least, sedimentary context all indicate that they were flighted animals and, likewise, clear anatomical distinctions between birds and pterosaurs indicate that only basic mechanical details can be treated interchangeably.

Comment: +1 for skepticism about the pterosaur heresies, which is ["wrong in just about every detail ... It’s just bad science"](http://scienceblogs.com/pharyngula/2015/06/12/jurassic-world-david-peters-and-how-to-rile-up-paleontologists/)

Answer (score -1):

Two more flightless pterosaurs have been discovered.

Alcione is a flightless nycotosaur.
http://reptileevolution.com/nyctosaurusUNSM.htm

PIN 2585/4 a flightless unnamed anurognathid
http://reptileevolution.com/jeholopterus-CAG.htm

Comment: Can you provide peer-reviewed evidence here for flightlessness here, rather than just links to your own webpage.

Comment: Sorry, but no. A ms. describing one were rejected because I had not seen the specimen recently, after I had seen it a year earlier. That bogus rejection was only one of the reasons why I decided to start the web page. All the data is there for anyone to judge the validity of the reconstructions.